# rephrase "as they are mutually understood"

Tags: meaning-in-context, terminology, phrase-meaning, legalese

I'm trying to translate an SLA ( Service Level Agreement ) from English to Dutch. But i can't wrap my head around the following sentence:

> This Agreement outlines the parameters of all IT services covered as
>   they are mutually understood by the primary stakeholders.

The first part isn't difficult, but I'm having problems with the second part:

> as they are *mutually understood* by...

Can somebody rephrase this line please? Maybe that helps me with translating this line to.

Comment: The *mutually* bit is really just emphasising that all parties have *the **same** understanding* of exactly what all all these parameters are. Pretty much equivalent to *as understood and **agreed*** by all parties.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Ah, I see. That makes it a lot more clear. If you could put that into an answer I could thank you for your help with accepting it.

Comment: Sorry - I'm (just about) prepared to leave this one open in case there's something to it that hasn't occurred to me, but really I think it's probably General Reference on a site targeted at [linguists, etymologists, and {serious} English language enthusiasts](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I see. I'm really sorry for that. Should i delete my question then?

Comment: Don't delete the question on my account! When I said *"I'm prepared to leave it open"* I didn't mean *"I refrained from closing it"*. I only have one vote here, and it would need 4 others to agree even if I *had* closevoted (which I didn't). Unless lots of other people downvote or closevote, I think you yourself should leave it open. It would be *very* annoying if the question suddenly disappeared just when someone was about to post an answer they'd just spent some time preparing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mutual has two meanings:

- **Both** parties understand (**each** party understands)
- The two parties **share** the (same) understanding

> This Agreement outlines the parameters of all IT services covered as they are mutually understood by the primary stakeholders

This Agreement outlines the parameters of "all IT services covered as they are mutually understood by the primary stakeholders".

Both parties have/share an understanding of what the "all IT services covered" are.

I'm not sure (for example because I am not a lawyer) whether the agreement outlines the parameters of the services, or the parameters of the understanding.

Answer (score 2):

All agreements to provide goods or services, or to establish a commercial relationship are legally considered contracts.

Contract law requires that there is a *meeting of the minds*.  That is, the contract (whether written or oral) must reflect what both parties understand and what is supposed to be done on each side, regarding all important areas of the agreement. If there is not agreement, there is no contract.

This sounds like a stab at documenting this *meeting of the minds*. In plain English it could read

> This Agreement outlines the all important aspects of the IT services to be provided, and it describes what the primary stakeholders understand, and have agreed to.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your answer. That makes it a lot more clear. But as FumbleFingers stated out, shouldn't I just delete this question, because it doesn't belong here?

Comment: If FumbleFingers wants it deleted, he can vote to close. But as he indicated, there may be aspects of questions and answers that may be of interest and value to others who come to the site.